# ng test template parse error 'ngb-carousel' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

First I have created a new project using the angular cli using the following command

```
ng new my-project
```

Then I installed bootstrap 4 using the instructions from the [angular-cli readme](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation)

After that I installed [NG Bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#installation)

I then created a new component using the following command

```
ng g component my-carousel
```

I then used the following markup to render a carousel in my-carousel/my-carousel.component.html

```
<ngb-carousel class="app-my-carousel">
  <template ngbSlide>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=1" alt="First">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First</h3>
      <p>First description</p>
    </div>
  </template>
  <template ngbSlide>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=2" alt="Second">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Second</h3>
      <p>Second description</p>
    </div>
  </template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

I am able to view the carousel in a browser but when I execute the tests with the following command

```
ng test --single-run
```

I get the following error

> 'ngb-carousel' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'ngb-carousel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ngb-carousel' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   t o suppress this message.

Here is the code for the test my-carousel.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { MyCarouselComponent } from './my-carousel.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

describe('MyCarouselComponent', () => {
  let component: MyCarouselComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyCarouselComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyCarouselComponent ],
      imports: [ NgbModule.forRoot() ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyCarouselComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should render the bootstrap carousel', async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('ngb-carousel')).not.toBeNull();
  }));
});
```

I searched around a little and found the following questions which are similar but not the same as my problem

[Template parse error in Jasmine test but not actual app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40715688/template-parse-error-in-jasmine-test-but-not-actual-app)
[Angular2 Cli Test (Webpack) Erros: “Error: Template parse errors”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640020/angular2-cli-test-webpack-erros-error-template-parse-errors)

Comment: It works for me. Can you add `app.component.html` and `app.component.spec.ts`? Maybe your error is coming from `app.component.spec.ts`

Comment: The tests in app.component.spect.ts were failing for a number of reasons, first because I wasn't importing NgbModule and then after that I needed to remove the async call from some of the tests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Karma Test 'component-name' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504468/angular-2-karma-test-component-name-is-not-a-known-element)

Answer (score 4):

To get this working I needed to alter the specs for the app component to include `NgbModule` and I learned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41104282/7237069) answer that I need to remove the async() calls from some of the tests

this is the spec for app.component.spec.ts

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { MyCarouselComponent } from './my-carousel/my-carousel.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MyCarouselComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot()
      ]
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it(`should have as title 'app works!'`, async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('app works!');
  }));

  it('should render title in a h1 tag', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    let qry = compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent
    expect(qry).toContain('app works!');
  });

  it('should render the carousel component', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    let qry = compiled.querySelector('app-my-carousel').textContent;
    expect(qry).not.toBeNull();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue. But, after importing bootstrap module **NgbModule** it's solved. Here I used lazy loading concept in my application. So i imported that bootstrap module in the component related module.ts file.

```
 /* in my career.module.ts */ 
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

 @NgModule({
 declarations: [CareerComponent],
 imports: [CommonModule, NgbModule],
 })
 export class CareerModule {}
```